# How to import a C# Programm into a sharepoint

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I´ve got a Question. I wrote a program and we as a company want to use this program now as an Add-In with our SharePoint. Is there a way I can "copy-paste" it? Or do I have to rewrite this program? Thank you guys!

Comment: The main question is how fancy is your copy machine. Also, what did you write this program in? What version? What libraries did you use?

Comment: What does your program do ? when you make it as add-in to SharePoint, there are 2 ways, depending on what the program does. see [SharePoint addins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins)